# Hi, can anyone tell me how to share text and image on instagram from app using titanium/appcelerator?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, titanium-android

i am developing a social app. Into that i have to share text and images to social sites like Facebook, twitter and Instagram. I have done it for Facebook and Twitter but not getting idea for Instagram. Can anybody suggest me?

Comment: Have a look at the [Instagram api](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) i think is the best start for your goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instagram doesn't allow you to post with their API just yet. Hootsuite was just granted access to post to Instagram, so hopefully it's coming for the rest of us.

The only thing you could do would be to pass your image and text to the Instagram app itself and post from there. https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/

Answer (score 0):

Instagram doesn't allow to post images from the API. You can send the images to the app. The easiest way to do this with Titanium is using existing modules.

Take a look to https://github.com/boardmain/TiOpenToInstagram and https://github.com/atsusy/TiInstagramUtil